# How can i move images up to down using keyframe

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I want my image to start with top:0 and ends with bottom:0 with smooth animation. I am struggling to find out the solution.

To be very clear i cannot use background images for SEO purpose. JS solutions are also welcome.

```css
.element {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element img {
  animation: nudge 5s linear infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes nudge {
  0%, 100% {
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }

  50% {
    bottom: 0%;
    top: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://www.neelnetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ecommerce-bg.png" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: use animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

Comment: there are multiple images .. and i don't know the image height..

Comment: no.. i want it to start again from begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to animate on top and bottom, you can animate on translateY and move it down with top so it doesnt go off screen

```css
.element {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element img {
  animation: nudge 2s linear infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

@keyframes nudge {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element"><img src="https://www.neelnetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ecommerce-bg.png" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: i have div's with multiple heights.. some are of 200 px some of 400px etc.. else your answer is nice

Comment: alright then, i edited it so you dont need the height anymore